# In Firebird using SIMILAR TO how to find if several words match

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and I have to find rows containing several word in any order:

find 'blue' **and** 'house':

'a blue house in the woods' = true
'a house with blue windows' = true
'a house by the beach' = false
'the blue car' = true

Using a pipe "|" give me OR and I need AND but in any order, not only with 2 words, could be more
I'm trying using SIMILAR TO but seems that RegExpr in Firebird is too limited.

Using several LIKE x AND LIKE y, is not the way yo go because I don't know how many words will have to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there isn't anything built-in to firebird that is going to help you.

What you really need is a full text search. Although this is not directly supported by firebird, there are some useful suggestion here: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq328/

Best of luck and sorry I don't have a more direct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your task using Firebird means only. Assume, you have a table named TEST with sole field S.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (S VARCHAR(256))
```

Which contains phrases:

```
  'a blue house in the woods' 
  'a house with blue windows' 
  'a house by the beach' 
  'the blue car'
  ...
```

You will need create an auxiliary selectable procedure SPLIT_WORDS:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE split_words (S VARCHAR(256))
  RETURNS(
    K VARCHAR(256),
    W VARCHAR(256))
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE B INTEGER = 1;
  DECLARE VARIABLE E INTEGER = 1;
  DECLARE VARIABLE C CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  K = :S;
  WHILE (:E <= CHAR_LENGTH(:S)) DO
  BEGIN
    C = UPPER(SUBSTRING(:S FROM :E FOR 1));
    IF (:C < 'A' OR :C > 'Z') THEN
    BEGIN
      W = SUBSTRING(:S FROM :B FOR (:E - :B));

      IF (:W > '') THEN
        SUSPEND;

      WHILE (:E <= CHAR_LENGTH(:S)) DO
      BEGIN
        C = UPPER(SUBSTRING(:S FROM :E FOR 1));
        IF (:C >= 'A' AND :C <= 'Z') THEN
          LEAVE;
        E = :E + 1;
      END

      B = :E;
    END
    E = :E + 1;
  END

  W = SUBSTRING(:S FROM :B FOR (:E - :B));
  IF (:W > '') THEN
    SUSPEND;
END
```

The procedure designed to split given string into words. Any non letters chars are treated as separators.

Having this procedure one can write a query wich will returns all strings with both words 'HOUSE' and 'BLUE' in any order.

```
SELECT
  tt.s
FROM
  test tt JOIN
    (SELECT
        t.s, COUNT(s2.w) c
      FROM
        test t LEFT JOIN split_words(t.s) s ON 1=1
          LEFT JOIN split_words('blue house') s2 ON s.w=s2.w
      WHERE
        s2.w IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY
        1
     ) ttt ON ttt.s = tt.s
WHERE
  ttt.c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM split_words('blue house'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [SIMILAR TO](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-similar-to.html) in reference manual but I think what you need is more something like [Sphinx](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/other-downloads/)